# Datepicker stop working after appending HTML Form - AJAX response appending

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker

related question, to the previous one:

I trigger html new form, by changing data to one of it's select input field. the form is being replaced successfully via AJAX response + JQUERY binding (after I change input value to its first input field, AJAX call is being carried out to the server written in PHP. the response of the AJAX is a new but almost identical html form created by the php server) I see the answer form in network tab of chrome, and its perfect. I bind it to form's parent div element perfectly. the forms swap perfectly.

However, the input date field lost its datepicker effect. here is the html line of the input field.

Comment: reinitialize datepicker after successfuld append from in ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initialized the field val like that
$("#birthday_99").datepicker({
                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear: true,
                            yearRange:'1950:2013',
                            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'})